# Any tips for displaying user dependent values in a list of items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It is pretty common for a web application to display a list of items and for each item in the list to indicate to the current user whether they have already viewed the associated item.

An approach that I have taken in the past is to store HasViewed objects that contain the Id of a viewed item/object and the Id of the User who has viewed that item/object.

When it comes time to display a list of items this requires querying the database for the items, and separately querying the database for the HasViewed objects, and then combining the results of these queries into a set of objects constructed solely for the purpose of displaying them in the view.

Each e.g li then uses the e.g. has_viewed property of the objects constructed above.

I think it is time to find a better approach and would like to know what approaches you would recommend.

Answer (score 0):

i wanna to know whether there is better idea also.

Right now my solution is putting the state in the redis and cached the view with fragment cache.